# Reference for an "elementary" combinatorial fact

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, symmetric-groups, root-systems

This is a question I've been meaning to ask for quite some time.

**Fact.** For $n\in\mathbb N$ consider the set of segments $R=\{[i,j], 1\le i<j\le n\}$. Let a subset $E\subset R$ be *nice* iff $E$ is closed under nonempty intersection, i.e. $$[i,j],[k,l]\in E\text{ and }[i,j]\cap[k,l]\neq\varnothing\implies [i,j]\cap[k,l]\in E.$$ Then there exist exactly $n!$ nice $E\subset R$.

Moreover, the map taking a nice $E$ to the product of transpositions $$\prod_{[i,j]\in E} (i,j)$$ (with the factors ordered by $j-i$ increasing from right to left) is a bijection from the set of nice subsets to the group of permutations.

This is, essentially,  Lemmas 3.3 - 3.4 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.08844).

**Question.** Has anyone come across this fact (or even just the above set of "nice" configurations of segments) in their or someone else's work?

**Update: comments on the construction.** Note that $R$ only contains segments of positive length. In particular, this means that if for a nice $E$ we have $[i,j],[k,l]\in E$, then $j\neq k$. This, in turn, means that if we additionally have $j-i=l-k$, then the transpositions $(i,j)$ and $(k,l)$ commute and the order in which they appear in the product does not matter.

Also, a list of all the $n!$ nice $E$'s for $n=2,3$ can be found in the comments.

Comment: how do you order those $(i,j)$ for fixed $j-i$?

Comment: @YCor Two transpositions with the same $j-i$ commute.

Comment: $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$?

Comment: OK, my bad, they commute _if_ the corresponding segments are contained in a nice set. The intersection of two segments as in your example is not contained in $R$, hence...

Comment: (Because $R$ consists of segments of positive length.)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the construction of $E$s. Can you give examples of all such sets $E$, say for $n=1, 2, 3$?

Comment: We consider all the $E\subset R$ with that one single property. For $n=3$ we get $\{\}$, $\{[1,2]\}$, $\{[2,3]\}$, $\{[1,3]\}$, $\{[1,2],[1,3]\}$ and $\{[2,3],[1,3]\}$.

Comment: (For $n=2$ we get $\{\}$ and $\{[1,2]\}$.)

Comment: This vaguely reminds me of https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.6904. I am not claiming any direct relation, but you might be interested having a look.

Comment: @ChristianStump Thanks! I can't say that I see a connection but the paper is quite fascinating.